# List all squared groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-groups

$G$ group is called "squared" iff for every non-trivial subgroup $H$ we have that the index of $H$ is $2$, list all such groups ?

I managed to prove that if such $G$ exist then there is only one group with index $2$ and i think just this group $\{ \pm 1, \pm i\}$ up to isomorphism

But not sure.

Comment: $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is another example. Together with $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$, they are the only ones. The assumption implies that $|G|=4$ (up to the eliminiation of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ for prime $p$ which have no non-trivial subgroups).